# Laravel Eloquent ORM relationship definition

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I have models `Clearance` and `Item`

every clearance has a specific item, but more than one clearance can have the same item.
Structurally, this just means Clearance has an item_id column.

So in the models I have defined `clearance` as `hasOne('Item');` and `item` as  `belongsToMany('Clearance')`

but when I call item, it gives me the error `clearance_item` doesn't exist, so I think I must have defined the relationship wrong. I try with belongsTo (assuming that many will trigger wanting a join table), and I get things back, but not the items don't have the clearances in the return data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it should be:

```
class Clearance extends Eloquent
{
 public function item()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('Item');
 }

}

class Item extends Eloquent
{
 public function clearances()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('Clearance');
 }
}
```

Have you tried this? You can also go through the [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent) again to see how relationships are defined